# How To Convert C# Class Properties Into Json File

Tags: c#, json

Iam trying to create jsonObject and json array by using the c# class and its properties containing values. Please see the complete code below.

```
public class Product
    {
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        public String Address { get; set; }
    }


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Product pr = new Product();
        pr.Id = 10;
        pr.FirstName = "John";
        pr.LastName = "ab";
        pr.Address  = "My Add1";

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pr,Formatting.Indented);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"d:\abcjson.json", json);
    }
```

The above code give the below Output

```
{
  "Id": 10,
  "FirstName": "John",
  "LastName": "ab",
  "Address":  My Add1,
}
```

But i need the following output followed by jsonObject and jsonArray. Please any guide how can i get the below output by using the above json code under button click. Thanks in advance.

```
{
"Product":[
  { 
    "Id": 10, 
    "FirstName ":"John", 
    "lastName":"ab", 
    "Address":My add1
  }
]
}
```

Comment: there is a pretty decent online tool that allows you to enter JSON and it will produce a C# class that reflects it.  just google "json to c# converter" or something. the website is actually called csharp2json.com or something iirc

Comment: it might be as simple as creating another class to act as a root for this current one. just something like public class rootProduct() { public Product product {get; set;} } and then you serialize the rootProduct after declaring all of the stuff like "rootProduct.Product.ID = 10;"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The thing to do is take look at the JSON you want. It's an object, with a `Product` property, which is an array of product objects.

So the simplest way to do that is create a class modelling that:

```
public class JsonRoot
{
    [JsonProperty("Product")]
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can just use:

```
var root = new JsonRoot { Products = new List<Product> { pr } };
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented);
```

You could use an anonymous type instead, potentially:

```
var root = new { Product = new[] { pr } };
```

I personally don't *tend* to like mixing anonymous types with named types for serialization, but it should work okay...

Comment: Thanks for reply, Do you mean should i create a separate class to get my desired output?  If yes, then my question is why you say to it as JsonRoot ? Sorry for my silly question but i need to clear my confusion.

Comment: And why u called it JsonProperty like  [JsonProperty("Product")]. thanks

Comment: @RaufAbid: I've called it `JsonRoot` because you'd use it as the root object for your JSON output. I've used the `JsonProperty` attribute to "rename" the `Products` property (idiomatic C# due to being plural) to `Property` in the JSON.

Comment: Is   [JsonProperty("Product")]   responsible to create root object like Product in my case? and what else more this object do? Also can you please initialized the Products list with some values to get Json result in multiple rows having comma between each array values, Really thanks and appreciate your help.

Comment: @RaufAbid: I suggest you read the documentation for `JsonPropertyAttribute`. In this case it's *just* renaming the property in the resulting JSON. And I've already shown you initializing the list with one value - it's just a `List<Product>`; if you initialize it with two values, it will do the right thing. Please *try* things before asking for further help.

Comment: Thanks Jon, Nice explanation and i got the desired results :)

Answer (score 4):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pr = new
    {
        Product = new[]
        {
            new Product
            {
                Id = 10,
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "ab",
                Address  = "My Add1"
            }
        }
    };

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pr,Formatting.Indented);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"d:\abcjson.json", json);
}
```

Comment: That won't compile for various reasons.

Comment: @JonSkeet, sorry. Copy-past and inattention. Fixed.

Comment: Much better :) I've included the anonymous type option in my answer - it's probably not what I'd do, and if I *did* do it, I'd do it at the last step, after initializing a regular `Product`, but that's just a personal style choice.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is put your object into a collection, as @JonSkeet suggested.

If you think, that is solution requires to create unusable things, such as `List<Product>` and separate json wrapper class, you can use anonymous type array, as @MarkShevchenko suggested, or make some work on [`JsonWriter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter.htm) class in the following way:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

    writer.WriteStartObject(); // {
    writer.WritePropertyName("Product"); // "Product:"
    writer.WriteStartArray(); // [
    writer.WriteRaw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pr)); // your object
    writer.WriteEnd(); // ]
    writer.WriteEndObject(); //}
}

var result = sb.ToString();
```

And the result string will be stored in `result` without creating anonymous arrays and separate classes.